# How can I require libraries in your Rails directory from the console?

Tags: ruby, console, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a script called query.rb in my lib directory. I want to require it so I can run it from the Rails console. I wonder if this is possible. The script work fine from within the application, so I know it's well formed and functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/query"
```

Comment: It says "no such file to load."

Comment: what does `Dir.glob("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/*")` say (do that in the rails console)

Comment: This would work too but it's require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/query.rb"

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 3+, use `load "#{Rails.root}/lib/your_lib_file.rb"`
load works like require, but allows you to re-load files as you edit them (unlike require, which you cant run again). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6361502/513739

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 4+:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/query"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> $:.unshift 'lib'
>> require 'query'
```