# Can Rails console reload modules under lib?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I have a module in my Rails project under lib.  I run 'rails c' and do some experimenting in the console.  I make a change to the module under lib, type 'reload!' from the console and it doesn't reload the file.  I have to quit the console and restart, which is real pain.

Is there a better way to reload that file?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129458/automatically-reload-rails-module/2138935#2138935) seems to have a solution for your problem

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Try this:

```
load "#{Rails.root}/lib/yourfile.rb"
```

Comment: Boom-shocka-locka!  Just what I needed.  Thanks, NullRef!

Comment: No problem! I had the same frustration. Thanks for accepting! Bumped me to 200. I was also going to come back and point you to `Guard` [https://github.com/guard/guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) which can do some awesome stuff when files are changed.

Comment: I have heard of Guard and it is very cool.  I need to use that in the future for reloading javascript files, so thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Is there an easy way to reload everything if quite a few files have changed?

Comment: To reload all rb files in lib: 
`Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**.rb"].map{|f| load f}`

You should beware that modules added to ActiveRecord::Base, for instance, in an initializer will not be reattached.

Comment: Where do I put load "#{Rails.root}/lib/yourfile.rb"?

Comment: Also, how do you reload ALL the files in the lib directory?

Comment: to reload everything:  Dir['lib/**/*.rb'].map { |f| load(f) }

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to `config/initializers/reload.rb`

```
class Object
  def reload_lib!
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/*.rb"].map { |f| [f, load(f) ] } #.all? { |a| a[1] } 
    # uncomment above if you don't want to see all the reloaded files
  end
end
```

You can now reload all the files in `lib` by typing `reload_lib!` in the console

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone interested, here's my findings on [how to auto-reload require files in Rails](http://teohm.github.com/blog/2013/01/10/reload-required-files-in-rails/) without restarting server.

The solution is now available as a Ruby gem [require_reloader](https://github.com/teohm/require_reloader).

Answer (score 0):

this is the monkeypatch that could help you, paste this in rails console (or you could put this code in a monkeypatch file - although I don't recommend monkeypatching Object with an utility method):

```
class Object
  def self.reload_myself!
    method = (self.instance_methods(false) + self.methods(false)).select{|method| method.to_s[0] =~ /[A-Za-z]/}.last
    if method
      if self.instance_methods(false).index method
        method = self.instance_method(method)
      elsif
        method =  self.method(method)
      end

      if (method.source_location)
        source_location = method.source_location[0]
        puts "reloading: #{source_location}"
        load "#{source_location}"
      else
        puts "could not reload #{self.name}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and you can call

```
reload_myself!
```

on any object to reload its source code.